# ¿Como leer un archivo html desde un modulo y mostrarlo en una aplicación web usando nodejs?

Tags: nodejs

Poseo la siguiente aplicación:

```
// para usar cliente y servidor http
const http = require("http");

// Para trabajar las url
const url = require("url");

// para leer archivos
const rf = require("./read_files");

const hostname = "127.0.0.1";
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    statusCode = 200;
    contentType =  {'Content-Type': 'text/html'};
    let t = rf.read_file("text.html");
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(t);
    res.end();
});


server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Y tengo el siguiente modulo llamado read_files:

```
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = {

    read_file: function(path){
        let fs_data = fs.readFile(path, null, (
            (err, data),=>{
                if(err){
                    throw err;
                } 
            })
        );
        return fs_data;
    }

}
```

Lo que deseo es poder retornar el valor de data que esta en el callback de fs, pero cuando reviso fuera de ese llamado aparece como undefined.

*¿Como puedo lograr retornar desde la función read_file del modulo read_files hasta la aplicación principal?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Estás usando la función [`fs.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback), que es asíncrona. Tienes dos opciones:

### Crear una función callback que gestione la respuesta

Es mi preferida porque no es bloqueante, que es el principal beneficio de usar NodeJS como servidor (un thread gestiona muchas llamadas)

```
const fs = require("fs");
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    statusCode = 200;
    contentType =  {'Content-Type': 'text/html'};
    fs.read_file("text.html", (err, data) => {
       if(err){
         throw err;
       }
       res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
       res.write(data);
       res.end();
    });
});
```

### Usar otra [función](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options), esta vez síncrona:

```
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = {

    read_file: function(path){
        let fs_data = fs.readFileSync(path);
        return fs_data;
    }
}
```

El hilo de ejecución quedará bloqueado hasta que se lea el fichero.

### Bonus: con [Promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise)

```
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = {

  read_file: function(path){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      fs.readFile(path, null, 
        (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          } else {
            resolve(data);
          }
        });
  }
};
```

Con lo que el código principal se quedaría así

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  statusCode = 200;
  contentType =  {'Content-Type': 'text/html'};
  let promesa = rf.read_file("text.html");
  promesa.then(data => {
    res.writeHead(statusCode, contentType);
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
  });
});
```

Comment: Perfecto, así esta bien